# In Python, how to tell if being called by exception handling code?

Tags: python, exception

I would like to write a function in Python (2.6) that can determine if it is being called from exception handling code somewhere up the stack.

This is for a specialized logging use. In python's `logging` module, the caller has to explicitly specify that exception information should be logged (either by calling `logger.exception()` or by using the `exc_info` keyword). I would like my logger to do this automatically, based on whether it is being called from within exception handling code.

I thought that checking sys.exc_info() might be the answer, but it also returns exception information from an already-handled exception. (From the [docs](http://docs.python.org/library/sys.html): "This function returns a tuple of three values that give information about the exception that is currently being handled... If the current stack frame is not handling an exception, the information is taken from the calling stack frame, or its caller, and so on until a stack frame is found that is handling an exception. Here, 'handling an exception' is defined as 'executing or ***having executed*** an except clause.'")

Also, since I want this to be transparent to the caller, I do not want to have to use `exc_clear()` or anything else in the `except` clause.

What's the right way to do this?

Comment: How can the calling context possibly be ambiguous?  You define a function **to be called from an exception**.  It's always called from an exception.  What's the problem?  Please provide some sense of why a function designed to be called from an exception would not be called from an exception.

Comment: I did not define this as a function to be called from an exception. It is a function that might be called from an exception or might be called from a non-exception. I want to determine which is the case.

Comment: Ummm... What's wrong with defining your function so it **must** be called from an exception?  What's preventing you from changing the the function definition to simplify this?

Comment: Or 'fork' your function into two: one called only from an exception handler, and another in all other cases (if I get it right).

Answer (score 2):

If you clear the exception using `sys.exc_clear` in your exception handlers, then `sys.exc_info` should work for you. For example: If you run the following script:

```
import sys

try:
    1 / 0
except:
    print sys.exc_info()
    sys.exc_clear()
print sys.exc_info()
```

You should see this output:

```
(, ZeroDivisionError('integer division or modulo by zero',), )
(None, None, None)
```

**Update:** I don't believe there is a simple ("transparent") way of answering the question "Is an exception handler running?" without going to some trouble, and in my opinion it's not worth taking the trouble just for logging. It is of course easy to answer the question "Has an exception been raised (in this thread)?", even on a per-stack-frame basis (see the documentation for frame objects).

Comment: Thanks Vinay, but I'm looking for a way to do this that is transparent to the caller; that is, that doesn't require anything special in the except clause. 
I'll edit the question to be more specific.

Answer (score 0):

Like everything in Python, an exception is an object. Therefore, you could keep a (weak!) reference to the last exception handled and then use `sys.exc_info()`.
Note: in case of multithreading code, you may have issues with this approach. And there could be other corner cases as well.

However, [explicit is better than implicit](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/); are you *really* sure that handling exception logging in the same way as normal one is a good feature to add to your system?
In my humble opinion, not.